# SfLinearGauge does not update data

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

I'm using this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_gauges), and I am faced with a data update problem, because when I pass to a `SfLinearGauge`   the `minimum` and the `maximum` value it keeps the old values.

Here there is the piece of code where I pass the values:

```
  List<SectionItem> updateSectionItems(int indexOfContainer) {
    items.clear();
    config = Project.getProjectPageDetails(widget.pageId);
    if (config.sections![indexOfContainer].items.isNotEmpty) {
      for (var item in config.sections![indexOfContainer].items) {
        setState(() {
          items.add(SectionItem(
            icon: item.icon!,
            label: item.label,
            min: item.min != null ? item.min! : 0,
            max: item.max != null ? item.max! : 100,
            unit: item.unit != null ? item.unit! : '',
            widthFactor: item.widthFactor,
            type: item.type,
          ));
        });
      }
    }
    return items;
  }
```

and here there is the piece of code where I use the values:

```
  Widget barWidget() {
    double min = 0.0;
    double max = 100.0;
    setState(() {
      min = widget.min.toDouble();
      max = widget.max.toDouble();
    });
    return FractionallySizedBox(
      widthFactor: widget.widthFactor,
      child: Container(
          padding: padding,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Text(widget.label, style: TextStyle(fontSize: fontsize)),
                  Spacer(),
                  Text(
                    '50',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  Text(' ' + widget.unit)
                ],
              ),
              Text(min.toString()), //here the value is correct
              Text(max.toString()), //here the value is correct
              SfLinearGauge(
                minimum: min,//here the value is correct, but in the GUI it isn't updated
                maximum: max,//here the value is correct, but in the GUI it isn't updated
                useRangeColorForAxis: true,
                showTicks: false,
                showLabels: false,
                barPointers: [
                  new LinearBarPointer(
                    value: 50,
                    color: Colors.amber,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
```

[here there is the example of what happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFQvm.png)